# non-ASCII characters *sometimes* not working as JButton text

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jbutton

I'm trying to make a gui with buttons that have some non-ASCII characters as their title. (∧, ∨ and ↔ in particular) I am using strings like "\u2227" to accomplish this because trying to use "∧" causes me trouble. I made a little test GUI (writing all the code out in a .txt file and compiling it in the terminal) to see if this works and it does. Unfortunately, my gui is far too complex for me to write it all manually so I am using Eclipse's WindowBuilder instead. When I try to make this same button in Eclipse, the button shows up with this symbol ( □ ) instead. This issue persists if I run the eclipse-generated code outside of eclipse so there must be something wrong with the code and not just an eclipse error. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on here.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Test Code (worked):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class IncDecPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
   public TestPanel()
   {
      incButton = new JButton("\u2227");
   }
}
```

Eclipse generated code (Button has wrong symbol) I hacked this down from 1000+ lines to only show the relevant code but even when running just this portion the problem persists.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Test {
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test window = new Test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Test() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 350, 361);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane_1 = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane_1, "name_7199196968440");

    JPanel logicPanel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane_1.addTab("Logic", null, logicPanel, null);
    GridBagLayout gbl_logicPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_logicPanel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_logicPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_logicPanel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_logicPanel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    logicPanel.setLayout(gbl_logicPanel);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("\u2227");
    button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    button_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_button_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_button_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_button_1.gridx = 5;
    gbc_button_1.gridy = 2;
    logicPanel.add(button_1, gbc_button_1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The eclipse code works fine here.

Comment: @JBNizet It doesn't work for me and I've tried running it from eclipse and from the terminal on multiple computers http://puu.sh/uNMu0.png

Did you really run it and get a ∨ on the button?

Comment: Try changing the font. This is probably due to that. In Mac I cannot reproduce the error. Or change the project encoding...